# How do I define custom scopes for my OneLogin OpenID Connect (OIDC) application?

Tags: onelogin

When making a login request I can specify the following scopes: `openid, profile, group, params`

But I can't figure out how to specify my own custom scopes (e.g. `MyApp.ReadWrite`)

I've noticed that I can create + add users to groups and then request the group scope:

```
"groups": [
      "MyApp.ReadWrite"
    ],
```

But doing it this way means that I can't use the `access_token` to authenticate because it contains the following `"scope": "openid profile groups",` and not what I really want `"scope": "openid profile MyApp.ReadWrite"`

I was under the impression that I should be authenticating users with the `access_token` and not the `id_token`. Is this mistaken? Should I just be using the `id_token` to authenticate users?